# Facebook tag-like TextInput - React Native

Tags: react-native

I am working on a proyect right now, and I was asked to format text on  like Facebook does when you write or answer a post.

I was trying serveral ways of achieving this but with no luck.
TextInput can receive Text children, but as soon I write something else after Text component, all input transform in a string.

Also, I cannot format text style to match my needs (I need a box with border radious) since Text cannot nest a View.

Is this hard to do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, this cannot be done yet, since it can be done with Spannable on Android and NSAttributeString on iOS and those resources are not yet on React Native.

Answer (score 0):

You can try react-native-parsed-text, that’s what I’m using in my project

Answer (score 0):

```
import ParsedText from 'react-native-parsed-text'
...
  <TextInput
    ...
    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ value: text })}>
    <ParsedText style={styles.text} parse={[{ pattern: /#(\w+)/, style: styles.hashTag }]}
      childrenProps={{ allowFontScaling: false }}>{this.state.value}</ParsedText>
  </TextInput>
 ...
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  hashTag: {
    fontStyle: 'italic', color:'red'
  },
});
```

my solution:

- add library: https://github.com/taskrabbit/react-native-parsed-text
- e.g: *input value = "hallo #gshoanganh, welcome"*